# In go, how to inspect the http response that is written to http.ResponseWriter?

Tags: http, go

There's probably something obvious that I'm missing but I'm trying to debug the HTTP response written by my go server.

I see that there's [httputil.DumpResponse](http://httputil.DumpResponse) available but it takes a http.Response object and what I have available is http.ResponseWriter

Is there a way to extract the http.Response from http.ResponseWriter so I can inspect the content of the response to console or log?

Context:

I'm writing a simple server-side authentication using https://github.com/RangelReale/osin and it's default example, but could not understand why the front-end (using http://ember-simple-auth.com) interprets a failed authentication (incorrect password) as success.

Here's the snippet:

```
r = mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/token", func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    fmt.Printf("r.HandleFunc /token\n")

    resp := server.NewResponse()
    defer resp.Close()

    r.ParseForm()

    grantType := r.FormValue("grant_type")
    username := r.FormValue("username")
    password := r.FormValue("password")
    fmt.Printf("/token : grantType=%s  username=%s  password=%s\n", grantType, username, password)

    if ar := server.HandleAccessRequest(resp, r); ar != nil {
        if username == "user" && password == "correct-password" {
            ar.Authorized = true
        } else {
            ar.Authorized = false
        }
        server.FinishAccessRequest(resp, r, ar)
    }

    osin.OutputJSON(resp, w, r)

    // Debug - doesn't work yet
    dump, err := httputil.DumpResponse(w, true)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", dump)
    }
});
http.Handle("/token", r)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write to an [`*httptest.ResponseRecorder`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#ResponseRecorder) (which implements `http.ResponseWriter`) and inspect it.

Example from the package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
)

func main() {
    handler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.Error(w, "something failed", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com/foo", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler(w, req)

    fmt.Printf("%d - %s", w.Code, w.Body.String())
}
```

**Edit to answer question in comments:**

If I understand your question correctly, then yes, you can make use of closures for this.

Consider the following to be your handler:

```
func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // do useful stuff...
}
```

You could then register the following closure with your servemux to attain the desired effect:

```
http.HandleFunc("/my/url", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // first call MyHandler
    MyHandler(w, r)

    // then log whatever you need
    log.Printf("%#v\n", w)
})
```

If this pattern proves useful to you then you could write a higher-order method that wraps any `func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)` in such a closure. That's a topic for itself, though.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. Using that example along with refactoring my code I was able to hook my existing handler to an httptest.Recorder . However, is it possible to simply insert a log statement at the end of the func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)  handler itself? This way I can track responses while interacting with it on a browser.

Comment: @zaichang I have amended my answer to address your question.

Comment: Thanks thwd, the output I get is something like `&http.response{conn:(*http.conn)(0xc208048000), req:(*http.Request)(0xc2080268f0), wroteHeader:true, wroteContinue:false, w:(*bufio.Writer)(0xc208044580), cw:http.chunkWriter{res:(*http.response)(0xc20804ab40), .......... dateBuf:[29]uint8{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, clenBuf:[10]uint8{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}}` which seems like an object dump and I can't figure out how to get at the json message body.

Comment: @zaichang: please open a new question for this.

Comment: I've added the followup question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319783/go-logging-responses-to-incoming-http-requests-inside-http-handlefunc