# How to redirect *.appspot.com to custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, go

How do you redirect your *.appspot.com domain to your custom domain. What I want is redirect the domains like this:

`app-id.appspot.com -> mycustomdomain.com
www.mycustomdomain.com -> mycustomdomain.com`

Note: I am using go and gorilla mux.

Comment: Check the domain in the request and redirect it if it's not your canonical one. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: Do I have to do it to all of my handler functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `http.Handler` combinatorics as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29328884/532430) to reuse code.

In your case the combinator would look something like this (tweak it to your taste and requirements):

```
func NewCanonicalDomainHandler(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        if r.Host != "myapp.com" {
            u := *r.URL
            u.Host = "myapp.com" 
            u.Scheme = "http" 
            http.Redirect(w, r, u.String(), http.StatusMovedPermanently)
            return
        }

        next(w, r)

    }
}
```

The you can wrap your handlers with that:

```
 http.Handle("/foo", NewCanonicalDomainHandler(someHandler))
```

Comment: I tried this with `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`. When I navigate to `http://localhost` it will redirect to `http://localhost/127.0.0.1`

Comment: localhost is special. but hey, tweak the code, play around with it.

Comment: I finally got it, I changed `if r.Url.Host` to `if r.Host` then add `u.Scheme = "http"`