# Default App Domain not changing URL to the assigned Custom Domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

Hi I have bought a Domain from `GoDaddy` and I have assigned the `Forwarding` to my GCloud App url (`https://*******-***-1.appspot.com`). I also have assigned my `Custom domains` to my Domain in GCloud though I'm getting `SSL Security` error `DNS records could not be found. Certificate activation will retry automatically.`. I have also assigned the `Record` in GoDaddy of Type = TXT, Name = @, Value = google-site-verification=*******************************************, TTL = 1 hour.

So I cannot understand that whenever I run my Domain the URL of my App switched to it's original URL `https://*******-***-1.appspot.com`. How do I prevent this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to host the application on your own domain, you need to setup custom domains on Google App Engine (App Engine -> Settings -> Custom domains) and create `CNAME/A/AAAA` record(s) on **GoDaddy** (not forward record). For this to work you need to Verify your domain first.

Once you start the process on (App Engine -> Settings -> Custom domains), it will give all required steps (including verification steps)

As a bonus you get free secure (`https`) hosting.

Comment: What should I write for Host and Point To specifically?

Comment: Do you want to host your toplevel domain or subdomain? e.g. yourdomain.com or xyz.yourdomain.com?? If you toplevel you need to add A/AAA record as pointed out by Google App Engine. If subdomain you will add CNAME with hostname as `xyz`. Start your process from AppEngine (this shall give detailed instructions), not Godaddy.

Comment: I have already verified and assigned the Domain in Custom Domains in GCloud. I would like `mydomain.com`.

Comment: Then you need to add A or AAAA records. Host name would be `@`. Changes might take a while due to TTL. I guess you have the target IP addressed from GAE.

Comment: ok i'll try this and let you know later. So when ever I will run `mydomain.com`, the URL of my web app won't change BACK to the default original Domain right?

Comment: Yes, given that your removed the forward record also.

Comment: Thanks for the support. It is working now, when I run `mydomain.com`, it remains `mydomain.com` Thanks. Though I need a little more help. How can I redirect my GAE domain `https://*******-***-1.appspot.com` to `mydomain.com`? Whenever I run `https://*******-***-1.appspot.com`, the URL remains same, why isn't it changing to `mydomain.com`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?? This can't be done at DNS level. You need to check the host name in your program and return a redirect to right domain if you really want to this. But I feel it's unnecessary as long as you won't publish your appspot url

Answer (score 1):

> App Engine allows applications to be served via a custom domain, such as example.com, instead of the default appspot.com address. You can create a domain mapping for your App Engine app so that it uses a custom domain

Here  **[Mapping Custom Domains to your Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains)**, you will find a great explanation on how to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the support. It is working now, when I run `mydomain.com`, it remains `mydomain.com` Thanks. Though I need a little more help. How can I redirect my GAE domain `https://*******-***-1.appspot.com` to `mydomain.com`? Whenever I run `https://*******-***-1.appspot.com`, the URL remains same, why isn't it changing to `mydomain.com`.

Comment: Please take a look at this other post **[How to redirect appspot.com to custom domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145440/how-to-redirect-appspot-com-to-custom-domain)**